# Running tests marked as [Explicit] with dotnet test

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

Is it at all possible to execute tests marked with the NUnit `[Explicit]` attribute using dotnet test?

I have some tests which I would like to be ran as a separate build on Bamboo. They take a while to run so didn't want them to be included in the standard test run in VS so marked them with the `[Explicit]` attribute. I also marked them with `[Category("Nightly")]` so on Bamboo I hoped to have a step of:

```
dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=Nightly"
```

but as expected they still get ignored because of the Explicit property.

I tried explicitly naming, like this:

```
dotnet test --filter "ClassName=MyTests.Tests.TestClassName"
```

but still no luck, I've tried all of the possible arguments to dotnet test https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest to refer to the tests specifically but they still get ignored.

Has anyone managed this?

Rich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this Github issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/473) this is actually a known bug with NUnit3TestAdapter where tests marked as `[Explicit]` would not execute regardless of how they were referenced in the arguments to `dotnet test`. This has been addressed in the [latest pre-release version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/4.0.0-alpha.1) of the nuget package.